# AutoIT script for linux?

Tags: linux, autoit

As we know we are having AutoIt script for windows XP/2000/..etc.

Do we have same AutoIt scripts for linux machines?

Comment: You'd better ask this in unix.stackexchange.com or askubuntu.com

Comment: Related: [GUI scipting for Linux](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/22896/3474) at SR.SE

Answer (score 7):

This topic has been discussed many times on the [AutoIt forums](http://autoitscript.com/forum/). One of the more recent ones that I can remember is [this one](http://autoitscript.com/forum/topic/137451-possible-to-code-in-linux/), by far the most comprehensive about it is [here](http://autoitscript.com/forum/topic/123608-running-au3-scripts-under-linux/).

Some features of AutoIt do work under wine. However, some of the more powerful automation function are very windows specific so I doubt they will work perfectly.

However, wine is not the answer. You are much better off finding alternatives that are native to linux. A few ideas that might be worth investigating:

- Java, using classes such as `java.awt.Robot`
- Python, google for python automation libraries for linux, like [uinput](http://tjjr.fi/software/python-uinput/) or [dogtail](https://fedorahosted.org/dogtail/).
- Any of the tools listed on [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Linux_GUI_testing_tools).

Answer (score 4):

Look at [expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net/) or shell scripting or [xautomation](http://www.hoopajoo.net/projects/xautomation.html)

Answer (score 2):

#### xdottool

> Fake input from the mouse and keyboard very easily.

Home page: [jordansissel/xdotool at GitHub](https://github.com/jordansissel/xdotool)

#### AutoHotKey

You can use [AutoHotkey (AHK)](https://autohotkey.com/) under Linux by executing it under Wine. This is how `winetricks` are using it in Linux (see [`w_ahk_do()` in `src/winetricks`](https://github.com/Winetricks/winetricks/blob/master/src/winetricks)), e.g.

```
wine AutoHotkey.exe script.ahk
```

There is also [PYAHK AutoHotKey](http://pyahk.readthedocs.io/) Python library which integrates AutoHotKey with Python. Probably you can run AutoIt under Wine as well. The downside is that you can control only Windows app under Linux.

---

For general Linux automation tools, see: [GUI scipting for Linux](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/22896/3474).

For Python libraries, see: [Python GUI automation library for simulating user interaction in apps](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/42664/3474).

See also: [GUI testing tools at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_GUI_testing_tools)